# How can I set a default font for text pasted into Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I know that you can change the font for all predefined layout slides by going to View > Master in the menu bar.

However, when I paste new text into my slides, it is still formatted with the Google default (Arial, black). It's annoying to have to change this every time!

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied text and have it automatically match the format of your destination document.